# maven-surefire-plugin, DLLs and java.library.path

Tags: maven

I have a Maven dependency that requires a DLL at runtime. What I want to do is to simply have that dll in `resources/lib` folder and place its DLLs to the `target` directory. So what've I done is :

1. Added DLLs to `src/main/resources/lib`
2. Modified `pom.xml` to use argument **-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/lib** like so:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <forkMode>once</forkMode>
           <workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
           <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/lib</argLine>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

However I am still getting runtime error that DLL is not present in **java.library.path**.

Comment: Did my answer not solve your question?

Comment: Not really :( I remember I used a different solution (so I didn't really use this plugin). I understand that you'd like me to accept your answer, but I don't really remember. Suggestions?

Comment: Oh, no... don't get me wrong, it's just that people keep up-voting every now and then I come back to check it, is it's an unresolved question and so I wonder in what way it didn't work, (because this is one of those peculiar corner case scenarios)...?

Answer (score 18):

Your `<argLine/>` points to an incorrect path. Try this instead:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
        <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If this DLL will only be used for tests, you should put it under `src/test/resources`. In that case the `<argLine/>` path will change to `${project.build.directory}/test-classes`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly that didn't help. When I inspect the value of path like "System.getProperty("java.library.path");" I still cannot see the desired DLL. Any more ideas?

Comment: Try passing in the property as `<systemPropertyVariables/>` as shown here:


  http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables

Comment: Check here for more details and make sure you're using a version that's newer than 2.8.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-634