# Add dll to java.library.path using maven

Tags: java, maven, or-tools

I have a program that relies on a system library that I want to be able to run via Maven. I have configured the program fine and maven runs, but fails when it has to load the system library, which I do using:

```java
static {
  System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
}
```

Java throws me this exception

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniortools in java.library.path
```

I tried adding this to my `pom.xml` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199768/maven-surefire-plugin-dlls-and-java-library-path) question but that doesn't seem to work.

```xml
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
                    <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/jniortools.dll</argLine>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <PATH>${basedir}\..;${java.library.path}</PATH>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And this is how I load in the external jar

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.ortools</groupId>
            <artifactId>ortools</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/com.google.ortools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: `-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/jniortools.dll`. I would think you need to pass a path, not a file. So try with `-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/`

Comment: I get the same exception with the path instead of the file.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the right way to solve it but I came across a different approach into loading a dll.

So by replacing

```java
System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
```

by

```java
File file = new File("src/main/resources/lib/jniortools.dll");
System.load(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I was able to load the dll and didn't need the maven-surefire-plugin. Hope this helps anyone in the future.